# Changing background colour of a label in C#

Tags: c#

I need to change the background colour of a label in my GUI when a variable reaches a certain value. How would i go about doing this

Would it be something like this:

```
 if(timeLimit == value){
             Label.BackColor=System.Drawing.Color.Red;
         }
```

I need to be able to do this once the timer in my application reaches 5 seconds remaining.

I'm using Windows forms in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: what is your platform? the answer is different for winforms then for wpf then for asp.net, etc.  To get a correct answer, we need this information.

Comment: Sorry. It's windows forms. I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 8):

Whenever the event is triggered change the color with `labelName.BackColor = Color.Blue`

Comment: oh, hmmm...do you need help with detecting updates to the label value as well?

Comment: about your edit, yeah, you would do something like that. Except, if timeLimit is your label you would probably want to do: timeLimit.Text == value and then timeLimit.BackColor = Color.Red.

Comment: Yeh I need to not perform the check once, but for the duration of the timer to detect any changes.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I'm following you 100%.  So, I'm assuming the changing of the label backcolor is taking place in a tick event? And is timeLimit the label you want to change the color or some other value? (And I take it that I still haven't quite solved your problem, but I would like to help, so what part is still giving you trouble? :) )

Comment: Ok sorry for how vague my question has been. Basically, I have a timer and when it hits 5 seconds remaining, I need the background of the containing label to turn red.