# Changing Label's Image According To Variable?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make (using Visual Basic) a rudimentary questionnaire that measures multiple attributes and stores their values in an array and afterwards measures the attributes on a scale of 1 to 10.Now I've had the dumb idea to use a label for every single value of every attribute, and highlighting the right number by changing the label's image to yellow, instead of white(basically making the area behind the number a different color).
Now here's the issue: I can't seem to find out how to change a label's background image with code, which is what I'm asking. (I'm guessing the command should look something like "Label1.image = >image path<")

Comment: When you change the variable, change the label.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Sorry if I haven't made myself clear enough, I wanted to ask for the function or command that changes the label.
(Something like Label1.Image = image path)

Comment: Please read [Ask] and take the [tour].  You need to show more effort than just asking for code (or commands or functions)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436687/changing-background-colour-of-a-label-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple.

```
If text = No then
Label.Text = No
Else
Label.Text = Yes
End IF
```

You just have to change the text value of the label which is .Text = Text you want

And if your trying to show images, you should use the image control in the tool box, not a label

Comment: OP is trying to change the image, not the text